# problem with end letter in Arabic words

Tags: texmaker, arabic

I use the below commands to get an Arabic sentence

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cp 1256]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\Vocalize
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\centering
\color{blue}{يَرْفَعِ اللَّهُ الَّذِينَ آَمَنُوا مِنْكُمْ وَالَّذِينَ أُوتُوا الْعِلْمَ دَرَجَاتٍ }

\vspace{2.5cm}
يَرْفَع الله الذين امنوا منكم و الذين اوتوا العلم درجات
\end{document}
```

[image]
the problem is, when I use Vocalized marked (fatha, damma and kasra), the last letter it transformed to medial character look instead of final character look.
I use both Texmaker and TeXstudio, any help with that?

Comment: Use an `*` between the last character and the marke.

Comment: @touhami didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but it works for me.

Comment: do you hear about xelatex?

Comment: @touhami yes but I want to use pdflatex, because my thesis written all in English except for the page of the Quran verse.

Comment: can I use XeLaTeX and pdflatex for different tex files in the main tex file?

Comment: no this not possible.

Comment: well what is exactly the problem with `*`?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, still the same

Comment: @touhami I closed the file and reopened and it work.thanks

Comment: @touhami how can I change the font? I want to write a Quran verse.

Comment: you can try `\textthol{يَرْفَعِ اللَّهُ الَّذِينَ آَمَنُوا}` but i am not sure it's good for writing Quran.